# Install NVIDIA 820M Driver - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Im' trying to install NVIDIA 820M, but Ubuntu only accepts the alternative driver

[image]

If I try to install the proprietary, I receive a black screen and have to purge the driver to get the GUI back

I've tried the `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.40.run` provided on NVIDIA webstie, but it recommends to install via Ubuntu interface

Some safe way to install this driver?

Comment: Show us your card. Execute `lspci -vv` in a terminal and copy the "VGA" part into your question.

Comment: VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

Comment: WHY do you want to install an nvidia driver? You have an INTEL GPU

Comment: There is obviously an Nvidia GPU there.

Answer (score 1):

purge drivers

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep nvidia
```

remove all packages listed one by one or alternatively

```
sudo apt purge *nvidia*
```

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Search for all NVIDIA drivers:

   ```
   sudo apt search nvidia-driver
   ```
2. Install `nvidia-driver-390`:

   ```
   sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390
   ```
3. You might get errors for missing i915 firmware requirements of each module included when `update-initramfs` runs at end of installation. Fix this by downloading the missing firmware requirements here: https://anduin.linuxfromscratch.org/sources/linux-firmware/i915/
4. Move these missing requirements (.bin files) to `/lib/firmware/i915/` using nautilus:

   ```
   sudo nautilus
   ```
5. Finally run:

   ```
   update-initramfs -u -k all
   ```
6. Restart your PC/Laptop and check the installed NVIDIA packages:

   ```
   dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
   ```

   or go to Settings and check about: *GeForce 820M/PCIe/SSE2 / GeForce 820M/PCIe/SSE2*

These steps worked on Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit.